# How to refresh a page after download

Tags: jsf, primefaces, refresh

I have a commandButton that will invoke a function to download a file (standard stuffs like `InputStream`, `BufferedOutputStream` ...) After download success, at the end of the function, I change some values of the current object and persist it into database. All of these work correctly. Now when file is done downloading, the content of the page is not updated. I have to hit refresh for me to see updated content. Please help. Below are the basic structure of my code

`document`: Managed Bean
`getDrawings()`: method return a list of Drawing (entity class)
`CheckedOutBy`: attribute of Entity `Drawing`

```
<p:dataTable id="drawing_table" value="#{document.drawings}" var="item" >                            
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText value="CheckedOutBy"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.checkedOutBy}"/>
        ...
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{document.Download}" value="Download" />
```

Inside my Managed Bean

```
public void Download(){
    Drawing drawing = getCurrentDrawing();
    //Download drawing
    drawing.setCheckedOutBy("Some Text");
    sBean.merge(drawing);  //Update "Some Text" into CheckedOutBy field
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return two HTTP responses to one HTTP request.

To refresh the page after download, use [`PrimeFaces.monitorDownload()`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=monitor-status) in JS API and invoke [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) in the end callback.

```xml
<p:commandButton ... onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, stopDownload)">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

```js
function stopDownload() {
    location.reload();
}
```

In case you're already on PrimeFaces 10.x or newer then [`<p:fileDownload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) will support ajax ([as noted by Jasper de Vries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78123790)). You can use it to partially update the page.

```xml
<h:outputText id="checkedOutBy" value="#{item.checkedOutBy}" />
...
<p:commandButton ... update="checkedOutBy">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

In case you're not on PrimeFaces 4.x yet and thus can't find `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload()`, simply upgrade PrimeFaces.

Alternatively, use [`<p:poll>`](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml?jfwid=a28a1) to check for bean state.

```xml
<h:outputText id="checkedOutBy" value="#{item.checkedOutBy}" />
...
<p:poll ... interval="5" update="checkedOutBy" stop="#{not empty item.checkedOutBy}" />
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I am reading the chapter now. I will get back to you if I have more question. Thanks for edit my post, switch from `h:commandButton` to `p:commandButton`. I originally have it as `p:commandButton`, but I was worry that many people would not understand it, since `primefaces` tag only have `38` rating.

Comment: This isn't a rating, this is just the amount of tagged questions as far. As long as you tag `jsf` along it, it'll be spotted by the right people ;)

Comment: I am still a bit vague. So does my `p:commmandButton` become this `<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{document.Download}" actionListener=”#{document.update}” value="Download" />`. My entity Drawing have a boolean `checked` attribute which essentially tell me which `drawing` the user select. So it could be multiples drawings select to be downloaded. Therefore, my `update` method on the server, I dont have a clear idea of what to `push` down to the browser. Do you think I should put down the entire column of `checkedOutBy`, or somehow figure out which one need to be updated, and push them

Comment: Send a delimited/formatted string which you can process further in JS code. JSON format may be highly suitable here.

Comment: Currently, I dont think push is supported in Glassfish, according to people from primefaces forum. I guess poll is my only option. Do u mind elaborate what u said earlier: `You cannot start it using standard JSF/PrimeFaces components when the synchronous download starts. But you can stop it to let it do a self-check on the rendered attribute.`

Comment: Something like `<p:poll id="poll" interval="5" update="checkedOutBy poll" rendered="#{!downloadFinished}" />`

Comment: I see once you done downloading, u set the boolean `downloadFinished`. You cannot start poll when the synchronous download start because the download use up the only one HTTP request

Comment: I did not like `polling` too much, since it keep refresh the table when it does not need too. I redesign, so that it took me to a confirm page, so when the user done downloading, they click `Back` to return back to the list, at which point, a new Http request is created and refresh the page. I marked this your post as solution, since it `push` and `poll` actually work well, just not for me :D

Comment: Okay, I'm going to +1 this question and BalusC's answer (of course). Great recommendation, BalusC, about using push or poll to do some javascript on the client/page to refresh the page. @ThangPham, yes, there were issues with PrimeFaces Push and Glassfish 3.x, but Glassfish 3.1.2.2 works fine with PrimeFaces Push (PrimeFaces 3.5) and Atmosphere 1.0.12 (runtime, jbossweb, tomcat, and tomcat7 JARs; those are the only JARs you need along with Glassfish 3.1.2.2, and look for Glassfish 3.1.2.2 topic in PrimeFaces Push forum). I'm going to try this to solve an issue I was  having with p:fileDownload

Answer (score 2):

Well, I decided to go with BalusC's answer/recommendation above, and decided to share my code here for people that may stop by here, 'later'. FYI, my environment details are below:

TomEE 1.6.0 SNAPSHOT (Tomcat 7.0.39), PrimeFaces 3.5 (PrimeFaces Push), Atmosphere 1.0.13 snapshot (1.0.12 is latest stable version)

First of all, i am using p:fileDownload with p:commandLink.

```
<p:commandLink value="Download" ajax="false"
               actionListener="#{pf_ordersController.refreshDriverWorksheetsToDownload()}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{driverWorksheet.file}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Since I have the xhtml above, and since p:fileDownload does not allow oncomplete="someJavaScript()" to be executed, I decided to use PrimeFaces Push to push message to client, to trigger the javascript necessary to unblock the UI, because UI was being blocked whenever I click the commandLink to download file, and for many months, I didn't know how to solve this.

Since I already am using PrimeFaces Push, I had to tweak the following on the client side:

.js file; contains method that handles messages pushed from server to client

```
function handlePushedMessage(msg) {
    /* refer to primefaces.js, growl widget,
     * search for: show, renderMessage, e.detail
     * 
     * sample msg below:
     * 
     * {"data":{"summary":"","detail":"displayLoadingImage(false)","severity":"Info","rendered":false}}
     */
    if (msg.detail.indexOf("displayLoadingImage(false)") != -1) {
        displayLoadingImage(false);
    }
    else {
        msg.severity = 'info';
        growl.show([msg]);
    }
}
```

index.xhtml; contains p:socket component (PrimeFaces Push); i recommend all of the following, if you're are implementing FacesMessage example of PrimeFaces Push

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="push/push.js" target="head" />
<p:growl id="pushedNotifications" for="socketForNotifications"
         widgetVar="growl" globalOnly="false"
         life="30000" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" escape="false"/>
<p:socket id="socketForNotifications" onMessage="handlePushedMessage"
          widgetVar="socket"
          channel="/#{pf_usersController.userPushChannelId}" />
```

Months (or maybe a year-or-so) ago, i found it necessary to add the following to the commandLink that wraps p:fileDownload, which will refresh the file/stream on server, so you can click the file as many times as you need and download the file again and again without refreshing the page via F5/refresh key on keyboard (or similar on mobile device)

```
actionListener="#{pf_ordersController.refreshDriverWorksheetsToDownload()}"
```

That bean method is referenced whenever enduser clicks the commandLink, to download file, so this was perfect spot to 'push' a message from server to client, to trigger javascript on client, to unblock UI.

Below are the bean methods in my app that gets the job done. :)

pf_ordersController.refreshDriverWorksheetsToDownload()

```
public String refreshDriverWorksheetsToDownload() {
    String returnValue = prepareDriverWorksheetPrompt("download", false);
    usersController.pushNotificationToUser("displayLoadingImage(false)");
    return returnValue;
}
```

usersController.pushNotificationToUser(); i had to add this one, tonight.

```
public void pushNotificationToUser(String notification) {
    applicationScopeBean.pushNotificationToUser(notification, user);
}
```

applicationScopeBean.pushNotificationToUser(); this already existed, no change to this method.

```
public void pushNotificationToUser(String msg, Users userPushingMessage) {
    for (SessionInfo session : sessions) {
        if (userPushingMessage != null &&
            session.getUser().getUserName().equals(userPushingMessage.getUserName()) &&
            session.getUser().getLastLoginDt().equals(userPushingMessage.getLastLoginDt())) {
            PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
            pushContext.push("/" + session.getPushChannelId(),
                             new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "", msg));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PrimeFaces 10 you can use Ajax file downloading ([showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) / [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=ajax-downloading)). This allows you to simply use the `update` attribute of the command button that triggered the download.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `update` attribute of the `p:commandButton` component to re-render the area that you intend to refresh after download, in this case your "drawing_table".

```
<p:commandButton update="drawing_table" action="#{document.Download}" value="Download" />
```

Comment: It's because of `ajax="false"` (which is mandatory to get the file to download).

Comment: Since PrimeFaces 10 you can use Ajax downloading.

Answer (score 0):

i also choosed the polling-way suggested by @Balusc.
To take overhead to the minimum i only start the polling once the button is pressed (autoStart="false"):

```
<h:form id='formOne'>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="checkedOutBy" value="#{bean.items}".../>
     ....
    <p:commandButton value="Download PDF" action="#{controller.downloadPdf}" onclick="startPolling();" ajax="false" />
     ....
    <p:poll interval="5" update="checkedOutBy" autoStart="false" widgetVar="pollWidget" oncomplete="checkPollCount()"/>
</h:form>
```

and adding this javascript for the called functions *checkPollCount* and *startPolling*:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    let pollCount = 0;
    const maxPollCount = 10; // max Poll-tries

    function checkPollCount() {

        var value= $('#formOne\\:checkedOutBy:selected').val(); 

        if (value === 'expectedValue after Change') {
            PF('pollWidget').stop(); 
            return;
        }
        pollCount++;
        if (pollCount >= maxPollCount) {
            PF('pollWidget').stop(); 
            pollCount = 0; 
        }
    }
   
    function startPolling() {
        pollCount = 0; 
        PF('pollWidget').start(); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As [Balusc](http://[1]https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) answered, we cannot get response twice from a single request.

To refresh a page after download, better use the following java script in download link(`p:commandbutton`) *onclick tag*.

**Example:**

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s" onclick="setTimeout('location.reload();', 1000);" action="#{managedBean.downloadMethod}" />
```

this will automatically refresh the page after 1 second, at the same time i.e. before refresh, you will get the download file, based on your download response time, increase the seconds in that script. **Seconds should not less than that download response time.**