# Update component after file download

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, download

I'm using Primefaces TabView, CommandButton and FileDownload to download a log file. Once the log file has been downloaded, I want to offer the option to delete the contents of the log from the server.

Initially the Delete Log File Button (deleteEventLogButton) is disabled and has a custom caption stating "Delete Logs - Export Required".  Once the log has been exported, the button should be enabled and the caption should state "Delete Logs".

The problem that I'm having is that the Delete Log File Button is still disabled and the caption reads "Delete Logs - Export Required" even after the Export event completes successfully.

My guess is that the exportEventLogButton->Update="deleteEventLogButton" is being called before the fileDownload value.

Once I've exported the logs, I can hit 'F5' and refresh the page and the deleteEventLogButton is enabled showing the correct caption.

**JSF - Snippet**

```
<p:tabView id="logView">
    <p:tab id="eventLogTab" title="Security Events">
        <p:panelGrid ...>

            <p:commandButton id="exportEventLogButton" icon="ui-icon-disk" styleClass="c25" ajax="false" title="Export Log" disabled="#{empty managedCmsLogsBean.eventLogEntityList}" update="deleteEventLogButton">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{managedCmsLogsBean.exportEventLogFiles()}"/>
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton id="deleteEventLogButton" icon="ui-icon-trash" styleClass="c25" ajax="false" title="#{managedCmsLogsBean.deleteEventLogCaption}" disabled="#{! managedCmsLogsBean.eventLogExported}" action="#{managedCmsLogsBean.clearEventLogs()}" update="eventLogTab" />    

        </p:panelGrid>

        <p:dataTable value="#{managedCmsLogsBean.eventLogEntityList}" ...>
            ...
        </p:dataTable>

    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

**Backing Bean - Snippet**

```
private boolean eventLogExported;

public StreamedContent exportEventLogFiles() {
    eventLogExported = true;
    return logFileUtility.exportSecurityEventLog(eventLogEntityList, eventLogStartDate, eventLogStopDate);
}

public boolean isEventLogExported() {
    return eventLogExported;
}

public void setEventLogExported(boolean value) {
    eventLogExported = value;
}

public String getDeleteEventLogCaption() {
    return eventLogExported ? "Delete Logs" : "Delete Logs - Export Required";
}
```

I tried moving the update event inside the FileDownload, but it didn't make a difference.

```
<p:commandButton id="exportEventLogButton" icon="ui-icon-disk" styleClass="c25" ajax="false" title="Export Log" disabled="#{empty managedCmsLogsBean.eventLogEntityList}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{managedCmsLogsBean.exportEventLogFiles()}">
        <p:ajax update="deleteEventLogButton"/>
    </p:fileDownload>
</p:commandButton>
```

I've searched for a couple of days now and have found MANY problems that come very close to this one... but none that have helped.  :(

Just to make things very clear... I am NOT having problems with the export.  The problem is that the Delete Log File Button is not enabled after the export is complete.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`p:commandButton` in your case is (an has to be) non-AJAX button (you set this by adding `ajax="false"` attribute). In that case `update` attribute and `p:ajax` tag doesn't have any sense (as they are only for AJAX requests). When you have file download your application sends streaming of some type, and you see *Save File* dialog. Your page is not refreshed. So you have to use `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload` to do this:

```html
<p:commandButton id="exportEventLogButton" 
                 icon="ui-icon-disk" 
                 styleClass="c25" 
                 ajax="false" 
                 title="Export Log" 
                 disabled="#{empty managedCmsLogsBean.eventLogEntityList}"
                 onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, stop)">
```

and add stop function which will update second button:

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="stop" update="deleteEventLogButton"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked beautifully.  I love this site... and it's because of people like you!

Comment: As you are new, if this helped you you should accept an answer

Comment: Thank you!!  It worked for me too , In my case i had to include ajax="true" with <p:remoteCommand name="stop" update="deleteEventLogButton"/>

Answer (score 5):

As [Balusc](http://[1]https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) answered, In [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471880/jsf-how-to-refresh-a-page-after-download) ([revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3473394/revisions)) , we cannot get response twice from a single request, to refresh a page after download, better use the following java script in download link(p:commandbutton) onclick tag.

Example:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s" onclick="setTimeout('location.reload();', 1000);" action="#{managedBean.downloadMethod}" />
```

this will automatically refresh the page after 1 second, at the same time i.e. before refresh, you will get the download file, based on your download response time, increase the seconds in that script. **Seconds should not less than that download response time.**

Answer (score 2):

From PrimeFaces 10, you are able to download files **with** `ajax="true"`. This allows you to update components as well.

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/filedownload?id=ajax-downloading
- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5978

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing  eventLogExported/isEventLogExported from boolean to Boolean or String ?

Comment: I have now... but it didn't make any difference.  Thanks for the suggestion though.