# Button not rendered after upload file

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, conditional-rendering

I want to render a button after upload a file, I have `selectOneMenu`to chose options, when I upload the file with the first option, the button didn't rendered but it rendered after I chose the second option.

ManagedBean.java

```
private boolean viewImport;    
public boolean isViewImport() {
    return viewImport;
}

public void setViewImport(boolean viewImport) {
    this.viewImport = viewImport;
}

public void processFiless(FileUploadEvent event) {      
setViewImport(true); 
}
```

import.xhtml

```
    <ui:composition template="./../../../../template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="form1" prependId="false">
                <p:growl id="messages"/>
                <h1><h:outputText value="#{customerData.importBatchTitle}" /></h1>
                <div class="formSection">
                    <p:panel  header="#{app['import.fileSelectionForm']}" id="importFile" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="300">
                        <h:graphicImage styleClass="formimg" url="/images/orange/fleche2.gif"/><h:outputText value="#{app['import.contract.parameter.primal']}" />
                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{customerData.parameterType}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{customerData.parameterTypeItems}" />
                            <p:ajax actionListener="#{customerData.selectionParameterType}" event="change" update="form1"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{customerData.viewUpload}">
                            <p:fileUpload update="form1" fileUploadListener="#{customerData.processFiless}" > 

                                <p:ajaxStatus>
                                    <f:facet name="start">
                                        <h:graphicImage value="/images/ajaxloading.gif" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="complete" >
                                        <h:outputText value="" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:ajaxStatus>
                            </p:fileUpload>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:panel>
                    <br/>
                     <f:subview id="modifyCustt"  rendered="#{customerData.viewImport}">
                     <p:commandButton value="ok"></p:commandButton>
                     </f:subview>
                  </div>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Comment: I tried to run the [mcve]  from your question but I get all sorts of errors. Sure it is a [mcve]? See http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: The subview is visible only when customerData.viewImport is true, you set it true only in fileUploadListener, but you don't udpate subview, or a parent, except on change of selectOneMenu (that's why you see it, on second change), so try to add an update in the p:fileUpload

Comment: @MatteoZanini I had `update` in `p:fileUpload` which update `form1`

Comment: Sorry didn't see it. I try to replicate your case and after the upload, I correctly see the ok button, so the problem could be in your template or in ManagedBean class; you can also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744778/update-component-after-file-download)

Comment: @MatteoZanini when I deactivate `ajax`, it rendered the button