# Unable to update a component after a download. Answer 15745235 does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PS: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/15745235/1763602 but it does not work.

I have a `p:commandButton` that downloads a file:

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="stop" update=":myComponentId" />

<p:commandButton
    value="download"
    ajax="false"
    onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, stop)"
>
    <p:fileDownload 
        value="#{myBean.download()}"
    />
</p:commandButton>
```

Unluckily, despite `myBean` changes (I see it using the debugger), the component does not update. I used `:myComponentId` in the `update` of many "normal" `p:commandButton`s without problem.

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.7 and Primefaces 3.4.1 and I can't update the software :)

Comment: @JasperdeVries it does not work either.

Comment: `ajax="false"` yet you are trying to do an AJAX call with a remote command after the download finishes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update component after file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744778/update-component-after-file-download)

Comment: @JasperdeVries Have you see the updated question? I already tried it without success

Comment: @MarcoSulla I tested and it works fine... on PF 7, 8, 10.  My guess is your PF 3.4.1 is so old there is a bug there.   Once again, it comes back to you are using 8+ year old library that has had tons of bug fixes since then.

Comment: @Melloware The question is specifically for Primefaces 3.4.1. This is not a forum of Primefaces, I suppose I can ask questions also for old versions. And I specifically added in the question that I can't update :)

Comment: Yep and I am telling you its a bug already fixed so why are people spending time trying to help when the problem is already solved?

Comment: Now is solved. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using, instead of `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload`, a recursive function, that calls `stop()` and check if exists an element that should exists after the update. If not, it re-call itself using `setTimeout`. An ugly trick, but it works.

I hope that someone will have a cleaner solution.