# Refreshing a JSF/PrimeFaces interface from the backing Bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

My goal is to display a text on a web page, with JSF and/or PrimeFaces. The text is updated in real time by a process on the server side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:body>
        <f:view id="view">
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{MyBean.init}"/>
            <h:form>
                <p:outputLabel id="output" value="#{MyBean.text}"/>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My backing bean maps the text to p:outputLabel. I also added to the bean a method foo() that modifies the text. This method is called by another process running in the background (it holds a pointer to the bean).

```
@ManagedBean(name="MyBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean {
    private String text = "text";
    public void init() {
        MyOtherClass.getPointer(this);
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public String foo(String s) {
        text = text + s;
        // ...and refresh ?
    }
}
```

What I cannot do so far, is to update/refresh the view automatically each time the text is updated. The best I could do is to let the user manually refresh the web page, or to use p:poll to refresh at regular intervals.

I have researched this, and I have found very similar threads; the answer is usually to use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() (JSF) or RequestContext.getCurrentInstance() (PrimeFaces) to access the component and refresh it. I tried, but the context is not available in foo().

I guess it's a lifecycle issue. I have a very limited knowledge of JSF. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `p:poll` an option? I can't really distill from your description whether or not you have ruled it out.

Comment: You can use PrimeFaces [push](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml) for real time updates but if you do not want to restrict yourself with PrimeFaces only (you may also want to deal with other libraries/frameworks in the future, for example), then go for WebSockets - an independent, full duplex protocol. (Updating something at a given regular time interval is essentially not a real time update in which something should happen (or be updated) if and only if something else happens or never happen otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a faces context from a bean when it is updated from a non jsf backend call. Use PrimeFaces push for this.

Comment: Thank you Kukeltje :) When I researched about p:push, I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471880/jsf-how-to-refresh-a-page-after-download -- if someone has the same needs, they can find some code snippets there.

Comment: The info in the link is old... better to keep an eye on the [PrimeFaces push examples in the showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml)